# Unable to parse string at position 0 problem

Tags: python, pandas

I use

```
"""Data taken from https://datos.gob.mx/busca/organization/conapo and 
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Entidades_federativas_de_M%C3%A9xico_por_superficie,_poblaci%C3%B3n_y_densidad """

total_population_segmentation = pd.read_html('professional_segmentation_mexico.html')
population_segmentation = pd.read_html('population_segmentation.html')
```

followed by

```
total_population_segmentation = population_segmentation[2]
total_population_segmentation = total_population_segmentation['Población histórica de México']
total_population_segmentation = total_population_segmentation.drop('Pos',axis=1)
total_population_segmentation = total_population_segmentation.sort_values('Entidad').reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
```

Therefore, I am working with the following DataFrame

```
    total_population_segmentation.head(5)
```

[image]

I used `total_population_segmentation.dtypes` and I got

```
Entidad    object
2010       object
2015       object
2020       object
2025       object
2030       object
dtype: object
```

I used `pd.to_numeric(total_population_segmentation['2010'])` to check if it works but I got

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "1 195 787"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-28db64f185e1> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.to_numeric(total_population_segmentation['2010'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    148         try:
    149             values = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
--> 150                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    151             )
    152         except (ValueError, TypeError):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "1 195 787" at position 0
```

When I look at each one of the values I obtain data that is decoded differently

```
In [1]: total_population_segmentation['2010'][4]
Out[1]: '4\xa0933\xa0755'
```

How can I convert this type of data to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you’ve got `[NO-BREAK SPACE][1]` character `xa0`

You should normalize your data first & convert it from string to integer. One way to do this is (this is just for one column) is like that:

```
$ df = pd.DataFrame([
{'Entidad':'BajaCaliforniaSur', '2010': '3\xa0224\xa0884', '2015': '763\xa0321', '2030': '763\xa0321'},
{'Entidad':'BajaCaliforniaSur', '2010': '5\xa0224\xa0684', '2015': '763\xa0321', '2030': '763\xa0321'},
{'Entidad':'BajaCaforniaSur', '2010': '4\xa0214\xa0784'  , '2015': '762\xa0321', '2030': '762\xa0321'},
{'Entidad':'BajaCaorniaSur', '2010': '8\xa0234\xa0684'   , '2015': '761\xa0321', '2030': '761\xa0321'},
{'Entidad':'BajaCaorniaSur', '2010': '8\xa0234\xa0684'   , '2015': '761\xa0321', '2030': '761\xa0321'},
{'Entidad':'BajaCalrniaSur', '2010': '2\xa0274\xa0084'   , '2015': '769\xa0321', '2030': '769\xa0321'}])

$ from unidecode import unidecode

$ df['2010'][0]
'3\xa0224\xa0884'

$ df['2010'] = df['2010'].apply(lambda x: (unidecode(x).replace(' ',''))).astype(float)

$ df['2010'][0]
3224884.0
```

Answer (score 4):

When you read the csv, add a parameter `thousands=' '` like so:

`total_population_segmentation = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv', thousands=' ')`

Then try again:

`pd.to_numeric(total_population_segmentation['2010'])`

---

As per your updated question, assuming that you have all columns other than first as numeric, try this:

```
for x in total_population_segmentation.columns[1:]:
    total_population_segmentation[x] = total_population_segmentation[x].map(lambda x: float(x.replace(' ','')))
```

Comment: I am using `pd.read_html()`. I will edit the question adding this additional information.

Comment: @Ivan Updated the answer, please try again